# Can't dispatch typescript action for class based component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-saga, stateful

I am trying to use [this](https://react-boilerplate.github.io/react-boilerplate-cra-template/) boilerplate for my react typescript project. I am unable to configure right type of actions. It was easy with JavaScript. But I am new to TypeScript. I want to know why my code is not working. Also please suggest the best way to solve this problem.

**Dashboard.tsx**

```js
interface IAction{
  type: string,
  payload: any,
}

interface IProps {
  // dashboard: DashboardState;
  dashboard: any;
  // Actions
  changeUserName: IAction;
}
interface IState {}

class Dashboard extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log("____FOCUS____");
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.changeUserName("NewName");
    console.log("____FOCUS____");
    // this.props.changeUserName('New Name');
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Dashboard</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Description of Dashboard" />
        </Helmet>
        <DashboardComponent username={'somevalue'} />
        {/* <Div>{t('')}</Div> */}
      </>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) => ({
  dashbaord: selectDashboard(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any, ownProps: any) => ({
  ...bindActionCreators({
    ...actions,
  }, dispatch),
});

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
const withReducer = injectReducer({key: sliceKey, reducer: dashboardReducer});
const withSaga = injectSaga({key: sliceKey, saga: dashboardSaga});

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withConnect,
  withSaga,
)(Dashboard);
```

**Types**

Types that I am creating are also as in docs.

```js
/* --- STATE --- */
export interface DashboardState {
  username: string;
}

export type ContainerState = DashboardState;
```

**Slice**

This is the slice I am creating. It is as described in docs.

```js
export const initialState: ContainerState = {
  username: 'Initial Username',
};

const dashboardSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'dashboard',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    changeUserName(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.username = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { actions, reducer, name: sliceKey } = dashboardSlice;
```

Comment: Could you share exactly what is not working? What kind of error message are you receiving? Also, you have a typo in your `mapStateToProps()` method ("`dashbaord`")

Comment: Actually, my code is no valid either. It is working but I do not have valid interfaces. If you can please tell me on that.

Comment: This expression is not callable.
  Type 'IAction' has no call signatures.  TS2349
this.props.changeUserName("NewName");

Comment: I do not have a proper interface implementation for reducer slice actions. Can you please give me an example of that?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [this guide](https://cansahin.gitbook.io/react-boilerplate-cra-template/building-blocks/redux-toolkit) for redux reducers

Comment: All is done same as in doc. But I do not have prior experience with typescript. I think I did not added right interfaces for actions.

Comment: I am adding slice in question.

Comment: Please review my question description. I have added more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

I was no creating interfaces the right way. The method of dispatching class based components was same as before. Only problem was interfaces that are now right.

**Solution Code**

Dashboard.tsx

```js
interface IProps {
  initChangeUserName: Function;
  changeUserName: Function;
}

interface IState {}

class Dashboard extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Helmet>
          <title>Dashboard</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Description of Dashboard" />
        </Helmet>
        <DashboardComponent 
        username={'somevalue'}
        initChangeUserName={this.props.initChangeUserName}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any, ownProps: any) => ({
  dashboard: selectDashboard(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any, ownProps: any) => ({
  ...bindActionCreators({ ...actions }, dispatch),
});

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: sliceKey, reducer: dashboardReducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: sliceKey, saga: dashboardSaga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withConnect,
  withSaga,
)(Dashboard);
```

DashboardComponent.tsx

```js
// ....
// This was a functional component
<UserNameForm initChangeUserName={props.initChangeUserName} />
// ....
```

UserNameForm.tsx

```js
// ....
this.props.initChangeUserName(this.state.username);
// ....
```